# Categorize object in JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, object, categories

I have the following object:

```
var object = [
  {
    "category": "Apple",
    "color": "green"
  },
  {
    "category": "Orange",
    "color": "Orange"
  },
  {
    "category": "Apple",
    "color": "green"
  }
];
```

I am trying to iterate the data via category, so the following would show in a list:

- Apple
- Apple
- Orange

Below is the code I've tried but unfortuantely it shows in the order it appears in the object. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
    function makeUL(object) {
        var list = document.createElement('ul');
        for(var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
            var item = document.createElement('li');
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.textContent = object[i].category;
            a.setAttribute('href', 'http://test');
            item.appendChild(a);
            list.appendChild(item);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Did you expect `object` to be automatically sorted? There's a `sort` method for that..

Comment: Sorting the array is not enough. Sorry I should of been clear with this. They need to be categorised so I can have headings, e.g a  Apple heading with the two apple listed below and a Orange heading with the one orange listed below.

Comment: In that case I'd still recommend sorting the items by their categories, but also appending a heading whenever a new category is used.

Comment: Could you show a mockup HTML file of what the result should be?

Comment: Sure. Thanks for help: https://jsfiddle.net/londonfed/3twd36hj/

Answer (score 2):

A solution with group change:

```js
var object = [{ "category": "Apple", "color": "green" }, { "category": "Orange", "color": "Orange" }, { "category": "Apple", "color": "green" }];

function makeUL(object) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    object.sort(function (a, b) { return a.category.localeCompare(b.category); });
    object.forEach(function (aa) {
        var a = document.createElement("a"),
            item = document.createElement('li'),
            p;
        if (aa.category !== this.last) {
            p = document.createElement('p');
            p.innerHTML = aa.category;
            div.appendChild(p);
            this.list = document.createElement('ul');
            div.appendChild(this.list);
            this.last = aa.category;
        }
        a.textContent = aa.category;
        a.setAttribute('href', 'http://test');
        item.appendChild(a);
        this.list.appendChild(item);
    }, { last: undefined, list: undefined });
    return div;
}

document.body.appendChild(makeUL(object));
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Thanks a lot. And thanks to everyone who took time to answer. It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your array to be sorted alphabetically ( DESC order, from A to Z ) you have to call the `.sort()` method first

```
function makeUL(object) {
    var list = document.createElement('ul');
    object.sort();
    for(var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        while(i<length - 1 && object[i].category == object[i+1].category)
           a.textContent += object[i].color + ", ";
        a.setAttribute('href', 'http://test');
        item.appendChild(a);
        list.appendChild(item);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jorel, sort is not enough because I need to categorise them: e.g. a heading Apple with the two Apples below. So I need a way to filter the data by category.

Comment: Edited : Now will check if the next occurence categorie is the same as the current one. The array needs to be sorted first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Array.sort

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sort the array before using it in for loop

```
object.sort(function(a,b){
   return a.category > b.category
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
object.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.category > b.category;
});
```

Result

```
[ { category: 'Apple', color: 'green' },
  { category: 'Apple', color: 'green' },
  { category: 'Orange', color: 'Orange' } ]
```